# Handling different user privileges in relational db

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database

Real quick for a noob like myself. I have two different users with different privileges in my database. Do I handle this by adding an attribute say to a 'User' table that indicates what access they have or do I make two tables for the respective users? The attributes for both users are the same aside from their access levels if that helps. Thank you.

Comment: Access rights for users at the database level are usually handled through the `grant` statement.  If you have specific access needs for an application, then you have not provided nearly enough information to answer such a question.

Comment: you really need to be more specific on the question, and you need to add a tag to specify which dbms you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Your specific question is answered by looking at the database inbuilt user permission with the `GRANT` statement, but since you have indicated you are new, and tagged this with database-design, let me answer with a more principle-based answer.

You never want to be creating metadata (tables, columns etc) based on difference that only pertain to data. Unless there is something intrinsically different about the fundamental nature of the users, they are the same and should be stored in the same table structures.

Data should not be a basis for designing metadata changes.

Look for points of similarity in what you are modelling and design around that, not the points of differentiation. You will avoid a world of complexity when you see things through the window of how they are similar.